# RTP timestamp increase is not constant in some cases. Why?

Tags: timestamp, rtp

During analyzing RTP packet stream, I found there are some cases timestamp increase is not constant.

```
E.g.#1 : 1579202786 - 1579207849 - 1579212913 - 1579217977 - 1579223040

E.g.#2 : 1187115268 - 1187115468 - 1187115667 - 1187115869 - 1187116069
```

In this case, timestamp increases are 5063, 5064, 5064, 5063 and
200, 199, 202, 200. Do you know why does this variation happen?

E.g.#1 RTP packet is captured at VLC media player using MPEG2 audio codec,
and e.g.#2 is captured at X-Lite softphone using H.263 video codec.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect it to be constant?

Generally presentation times or capture times are converted into RTP timestamps, there is no guarantee that they will be constant especially in the case of live capture.

With respect to the codec- this influences the clock that is used: i.e. H.263 uses a 90kHz clock, however the RTP timestamp is still derived from the presentation/capture time.

Comment: Thanks for kind answer. By the way, I checked voice RTP packets from some softphone applications, there are always constant timestamp increases. Then can I explain this behavior like this? "The RTP timestamp clock is 8kHz for voice packet, and 90kHz for audio&video packet. However media clocks are 8, 16kHz for voice and 44.1kHz for some of AV packet. Therefore timestamp can be increased not constantly in case of AV packet."....Am I right?

Comment: No, I think you misunderstanding somewhat: audio clock will stay at the profile defined rate usually equal to the sampling rate say 8KHz (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3551), video at it's own profile defined rate (90kHz for H.263). Each capture device will capture a sample at a specific point in time, these capture timestamps might differ by tiny amounts resulting in the slight variance in RTP timestamp difference.